# Structure for multi-projects with Typescript 2.0 in the browser

Tags: typescript

I do want to structure a multi-projects typescript 2 to work with modules in the browser. The projects should have this structure:

```
Util/src/main/ts/UtilClass.ts
App/src/main/ts/AppClass.ts
```

My UtilClass.ts is:

```
class UtilClass
{
}

export default UtilClass
```

And AppClass.ts is:

```
import UtilClass from "../../../../Util/src/main/ts/UtilClass";

class AppClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        new UtilClass();
    }
}

export default AppClass;
```

The problem is that I do not want to reference UtilClass with that path, or at least, not all times. I also do not want that the generated module imports reference that path.

My understand is that I could peek the Util generated declaration files and put inside my App project, but that will require copy everytime Util is modified.

What's the best way to make this structure work?

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem. You're basically talking about package management, for which there exists many tools, including npm, NuGet, bower, etc.. There are also build solutions which will automatically update those package management systems when something changes in the associated package.